# 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

This code:

```
import datetime
d_tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Model(models.Model):
    ...
    timeout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=d_tomorrow)
    ...
```

resuls in this error:

```
'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, date, timedelta
def tomorrow():
    d = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
    t = time(0, 0)
    return datetime.combine(d, t)
```

`models.DateTimeField` expects the value to be `datetime.datetime`, not `datetime.date`

#### 2015 Update:

[Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) makes this all much more straight forward.

> Arrow is a Python library that offers a sensible, human-friendly approach to creating, manipulating, formatting and converting dates, times, and timestamps. It implements and updates the datetime type, plugging gaps in functionality, and provides an intelligent module API that supports many common creation scenarios. Simply put, it helps you work with dates and times with fewer imports and a lot less code.
>
> Arrow is heavily inspired by moment.js and requests.

Answer (score 13):

`d_tomorrow` is expected, by the Django ORM, to have a `date` attribute (apparently), but doesn't.

At any rate, you probably want to use a callable for the default date; otherwise, every model's default date will be "tomorrow" relative to the time the model class was initialized, *not* the time that the model is created. You might try this:

```
import datetime

def tomorrow():
  return datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Model(models.Model):
  timeout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=tomorrow)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when using the model from django.contrib.admin. I had two similar models, both with a date field (and both using auto_now_date=True - complete red herring); one worked, one had this error.

Turned out to be

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.date
```

goes BANG, while this

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.date
```

works just fine. Which is kind of obvious after the event, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + timedelta(days=1)

class Test(models.Model):
    timeout = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=tomorrow)
```

Alternatively you could use `tomorrow = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: Still, same error. And no, I can't use that, since I don't want the time.

Answer (score -1):

I tried out your code and it worked just fine. Can you verify that you are not modifying/redefining the import in some way?

Also try this:

```
import datetime as DT
d_tomorrow = DT.date.today() + DT.timedelta(days=1)

class Model(models.Model):
    timeout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=d_tomorrow)
```

Comment: I fail to see how it is a duplicate for two reasons. (1) I asked a legitimate question/tip about imports getting redefined. (2) the code snippet I gave is not the same.