# Django AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: django, date, datetime

I'm trying to make a calendar template tag I found online work, but it's balking at using dates. I'm not sure, and datetime is just really confusing to me. Sometimes it works and I have no idea why, and sometimes it doesn't work, and I have no idea why.

My model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    unique_id               = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    subject                 = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)
    body                    = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_date              = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_time              = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date                = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_time                = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and the offending code in the template tag:

```
from django import template
from datetime import date, timedelta
from cal.models import Event    

def cal_month(year=date.today().year, month=date.today().month):
        event_list = Event.objects.filter(start_date__year=year, start_date__month=month)

        first_day_of_month = date(year, month, 1)
        last_day_of_month = get_last_day_of_month(year, month)
        first_day_of_calendar = first_day_of_month - timedelta(first_day_of_month.weekday()+1)
        last_day_of_calendar = last_day_of_month + timedelta(7 - last_day_of_month.weekday())

        cal_month = []
        week = []
        week_headers = []

        i = 0
        day = first_day_of_calendar
        while day <= last_day_of_calendar:
            if i < 7:
                week_headers.append(day)
            cal_day = {}
            cal_day['day'] = day
            cal_day['event'] = False
            for event in event_list:
                if day >= event.start_date.date() and day <= event.end_date.date():
                    cal_day['event'] = True
            if day.month == month:
                cal_day['in_month'] = True
            else:
                cal_day['in_month'] = False  
            week.append(cal_day)
            if day.weekday() == 5:
                cal_month.append(week)
                week = []
            i += 1
            day += timedelta(1)

        return {'calendar': cal_month, 'headers': week_headers}

    register.inclusion_tag('calendar.html')(cal_month)
```

it's this line:
 if day >= event.start_date.date() and day <= event.end_date.date():
that keeps failing. I can't understand why. It's a regular DateField. How do I tell Django to see it as a date?

Here is the maximum recursion error I get when I try to change the line to: "if day >= event.start_date and day <= event.end_date:"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapps/programgr/cal/views.py", line 37, in view_calendar
    return render(request, 'calendar.html', args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
    template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 99, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1292, in render
    return t.render(new_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 211, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1292, in render
    return t.render(new_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 211, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
```

This just loops until the end of the log where it says "Maximum recursion error."

Comment: It's *already* a date, so it doesn't have a `date` method to convert it to a date.

Comment: I can see that it's a date, but if I change it to "if day >= event.start_date and day <= event.end_date:" then I get a maximum recursion error. Is there something I'm supposed to do to get it to check this range if not convert it to specific dates?

Comment: There are no recursive calls in the code you've posted. Please post the traceback so we can see where the error is happening.

Comment: I can't post the traceback because it's a maximum recursion error (that's only if I change the code to "if day >= event.start_date and day <= event.end_date:"

Comment: I don't understand that comment. But at least tell us what call being recursed.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question. If I have the code as in the above example, it fails with "datetime.date has no attribute date." If I take out "date()" then it gives me a recursion error. Just that line. I don't know how to give you more details because the recursion error just emails me a thousand lines of code then truncates with "maximum recursion error."

Comment: In that traceback, it will show one function being called repeatedly. What is it?

Comment: Posted the maximum recursion traceback in the original post.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676794/datetime-date-object-has-no-attribute-date

Comment: The problem no longer has anything to do with dates. The issue now is that you seem to be actually using your `{% cal_month %}` tag in the template that the tag is rendering (calendar.html), so it calls itself infinitely. Don't do that.

Comment: OK, thanks for that clarification. I guess this means it's back to the drawing board as now I don't understand any of it at all.